# How to convert comma to period and period to comma in a single line

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a number like this `12,345,678.09` which I would like to convert to `12.345.678,09`
I am thinking of splitting the string with `.` and changing commas in the string to periods and then joining them with a comma.

```
string value = "12,345,678.09";
string[] parts = value.Split(new char[]{'.'});
string wholeNumber = parts[0].Replace(",", ".");
string result = String.Format("{0},{1}", wholeNumber, parts[1]);
```

I feel this method is very clumsy. Any better methods?

Comment: wouldn't make more sense to use numeric string formatting for a specific culture?

Comment: Did you mean "`12,345,678.09` to `12.345.678.09`?

Comment: Most likely he meant `12,345,678.09` to `12.345.678,09` as this is 2 different ways of representing the same number according to different culture settings.

Comment: @DanielA.White: there seems to be some problem with client machine where the code is hosted. The italian culture works on my machine but gives me weird values on my clients hosted machine

Comment: @Nikhil:Typo. I just wanna get over with it. Loong day pal. Sorry :)

Comment: @Jamiec: Yes. Thats it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *correct* way to do this (correct as in not string-mashing) is to use the [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) for the culture you're formatting for. Looks like you're after the italian culture `it-IT`:

```
var num = 123456789.01;
var ci = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("#,##0.00",ci)); //output 123.456.789,01
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/ARWF39685

Note that in a format string you use `,` to mean "number group separator" and `.` to indicate "decimal separator" but the culture info replaces that with the correct separator for the culture - in terms of Italian culture they are exactly reversed (`.` is the group separator and `,` is the decimal separator).

Comment: I was using `.ToString("c", ci)`. I will try this definitely. actually I created that string in the question using `#,#.00` why do you have a zeroholder before the decimal?

Comment: @naveen - No specific reason, your format string looks fine, just use the right culture info.

Answer (score 9):

If there is a symbol that does not appear anywhere in your string, say, `'$'`, you can do it like this:

```
parts[0].Replace(",", "$").Replace(".", ",").Replace("$", ".");
```

To be sure, this is suboptimal in terms of CPU cycles, but it does the trick in terms of staying on a single line.

Comment: +1: this was my other option :) is it not clumsy in terms of CPU cycles?

Comment: @naveen Of course it is wasteful in terms of CPU cycles -- it creates two objects that get thrown away even before the assignment is done. Trying to optimize it, however, would almost certainly be premature: at the very least you'd want to profile your application to see if this line comes anywhere near the top of the hotspot list.

Answer (score 4):

```
string value = "12,345,678.90";
value = string.Join(".", value.Split(',').Select(s => s.Replace(".", ",").ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

you have

```
string value = "12,345,678.09";
value = value.replace(",", "_").replace(".", ",").replace("_", ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with:

```
string newString = Convert.ToDouble(oldString).ToString("#,0.##", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk.aspx).
It's all in one line as you wanted and the recommended way to go.
You also can use other cultures, or `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, to show numbers the way the user is used in seeing them. If he's on an italian windows, he'll have `CurrentCulture == "it-IT"` and the number format accordingly. `CurrentCulture` is probably what you are looking for I assume, correct me when I'm wrong.
Edit: According to Jamiecs comment format doesn't work on strings this way, so I've added a conversion. But be aware: If the conversion doesn't work, it may throw an exception. So better do it in more than one line and use Double.TryParse() or something similar.

Comment: This wont work with `oldString` being a string - only works for number formatting. so `oldString` would need to be numeric - see my answer.

Comment: @Jamiec: Indeed, I've overlooked that it's not working with strings. So what is missing is the conversion of the string to a number, but I know no save way to do this in one line.